# Java : How do I set the background color of a frame to the corresponding selected color name in a combo box

Tags: java, swing

Please, I'm trying to set the background color of a frame to the selected color name in a combo box. Although I used the repaint() method, it still doesn't work.

Is it that the JFrame class can't be colored? Or, is there another way of doing this? What follows is what I tried:

Please can anyone help with some snippets?

Comment: Do you update your graphics? Try `container.repaint()`

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you do any debugging? Is the if statement of the listener code ever executed? I suspect your container variable doesn't point to the content pane that is actually displayed on the frame.  Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So all you need is the frame and the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating your own JPanel and setting it as the content pane. (Note where container is declared and the 2nd line of the constructor).  This is generally considered "cleaner".

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI1410 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private JCheckBox background, foreground;
    private JButton okButton, cancelButton;
    private String[] colors = { "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE" };
    private Color color[] = { Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE };

    private JPanel checkBoxPanel, buttonPanel;
    Container container = new JPanel();

    public GUI1410()
    {

        super("ColorSelect");
        setContentPane(container);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(color[0]);

        comboBox = new JComboBox(colors);
        comboBox.setMaximumRowCount(2);
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
            {

                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                {
                    container.setBackground(color[comboBox.getSelectedIndex()]);
                    container.repaint();
                }

            }

        });

        background = new JCheckBox("Background");
        foreground = new JCheckBox("Foreground");

        okButton = new JButton("Ok");
        okButton.addActionListener(this);
        cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.addActionListener(this);

        checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();
        checkBoxPanel.add(background);
        checkBoxPanel.add(foreground);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(okButton);
        buttonPanel.add(cancelButton);

        container.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(checkBoxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(400, 200, 300, 120);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

        if (event.getSource() == okButton)
        {
            container.setBackground(color[comboBox.getSelectedIndex()]);
        }
        else if (event.getSource() == cancelButton)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GUI1410();
    }

}
```